# Can I Drain Basement Sink into 4ft high washing machine drain?

Tags: drain, sink, washing-machine

i want to pump the water from the sink up and over into the washing machine drain hole

but nobody does this, the only way they combine the sink and washing machine drain is to drain the washing machine into the sink (i presume bc this is a pumpless solution).

just checking that this should work thanks.

Comment: My washing machine drains into the sink.   But they sell pumps to do exactly what you want.  Search: "sink drain pump".

Comment: thanks i already got the pump. the strange thing is they want you to pump the water a minimum of 6ft vertical (something about the check valve leaking if its less). not sure if i should pipe it up that high just to turn it down into the washing drain, or just take my chance with only 3-4 feet of vertical pipe.

Comment: Why not follow the instructions given?

Comment: Do you want to pump water out of the sink repeatedly or is this a one time operation? You could possibly siphon the water out of the sink by putting the end of the siphon hose in the washer drain far enough down so it is below the bottom of the sink. Is the drain on the sink plugged? There are pumps with a softer check valve or no check valve at all.

Answer (score 1):

The main problem I see with this (otherwise fairly standard drain pump arrangement) is that you're now trying to run **two** things into the washing machine standpipe. That's not up to code, and swapping the hoses back and forth gets old very quickly. If you put the pump on the sink drain, and drain the washer to the sink, then you're back to one thing in the standpipe (and pumping the washing machine water from the sink, as well as the sink water.)

Alternatively, plumb in a second trap and standpipe for the sink drain pump to use, so that the washer standpipe is still available for the washer to use.